# How to increase BufferHeight property

Tags: c#

I have a text file with 1000 lines inside my project but it starts reading from line **703** up to **1000**.

What has been gone wrong? Normally it should read all lines.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int b = 0;
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\blabla\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\DEV-data.txt");

            int subString = 0;

            foreach (string l in lines)
            {
                b++;
                Console.WriteLine(b+" Line "+l);
            }

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the comments, i will need to increase the [BufferSize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the console.

```
public static int BufferHeight { get; set; }
```

How can i increase the BufferHeight property so my console can be able to print all 1000 lines?

Comment: What happens when you step through your code?  What are you observing?

Comment: Well it outputs 297 lines and not 1000

Comment: Is it that you only see 297 lines since the console buffer can only show the latest 297 lines?

Comment: Check the value of `Console.BufferHeight` - console windows have vertical and horizontal buffers, so it might be that it's printing all 1000 lines, but you are only able to scroll up to line 703 due to the buffer.

Comment: I'm not asking what it outputs.  What happens when you step through the code line by line and look at the variables, look at where the program flow is going?  For instance, you assign `0` to `b`...are you saying the first thing you see is `297`?  Watch the value of `b` and see what's actually going on.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` is pretty reliable; if you're saying that the last line you see is "297 Line {something}", then frankly: I'd check whether the file really contains 1000 lines - maybe it isn't copying to the output directory, for example. What makes you think there are 1000 lines? If you're saying it outputs just "703 Line {whatever}" thru "1000 Line {whatever}" - then it read all of them - the problem is probably your console output buffer, *not* anything to do with this code

Comment: I had no idea about the buffer, i was also very sure about my code. So is there a way to change the buffer size?

Comment: The default for `BufferHeight` and `BufferWidth` are 300 rows and 85 columns respectively. This indicates that you indeed need to increase the `Console.BufferHeight` property and set it to greater that 1000. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferheight?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Okay guys i will try to edit the question if anyone can answer this, cool

Comment: And what is your question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for [BufferHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferheight?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [BufferWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferwidth?view=netframework-4.7.2) are 300 rows and 85 columns respectively. This indicates that you indeed need to increase the `Console.BufferHeight` property and set it to greater than 1000.

Max value for BufferHeight is `Int16.MaxValue - 1`.

```
...
Console.BufferHeight = 1200;

foreach (string l in lines)
{
  b++;
  Console.WriteLine(b+" Line "+l);
}
...
```